# Determining the Impedance of the antenna on a known circuit

Tags: antenna, transmission-line, homework

I am stuck on how to approach the following problem:

I have a graph with both the response of a short-circuit and an unknown impedance antenna.

[image: Ampedance of Short-circuit vs unknown impedance antenna]

The only information I have from this graph is the amplitude of the response and the distance between the minimas of both the antenna and the short circuit on the same circuit.

I worked through the different parts of the schematics of this circuit, but the only question remaining is how to determine the impedance of the antenna.

The vertical axis is the normalized amplitude of the response and the horizontal axis is the distance of the reading on the slot line.

My first reflex would be to use the SWR of the antenna response, but since it's already a normalized amplitude, can I do that? If I can use the SWR there, I can find the reflection coefficients with the rest of the known circuit, but the teacher told us that there is no complex calculation to be done : we can use the figure above to find out the impedance of the antenna.

I asked a few questions to my teacher, but since this is a graded work, he can't give me all the answers I am looking for to complete my work.

Thank you for your help.

edit : following the comments I received, I forgot to give the Z of the slot line which is 50 ohms.

Comment: 1. Don't worry that the graph is normalised. All that matters is the ratio of peak to trough. Impedance is also a ratio, V/I, where the actual voltage is not visible, right? So write an expression for SWR in terms of \$|\Gamma|\$ and solve, now you have the magnitude of \$\Gamma\$

Comment: 2. Draw more red lines in on the graph, for \$Z=\infty\$, \$Z=+jZ_0\$ and \$Z=-jZ_0\$. I assume you know \$Z_0\$ of the line... These will tell you in which quadrant the impedance lies.

Comment: 3. Write an expression for \$\angle\Gamma\$ using the wavelength (about 0.34 m), the position of the null, and what you learned in (2).

Comment: 4. Find complex \$\Gamma\$ and convert to impedance using \$Z_0\$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations, that makes a lot more sense.